# Do complex symmetric matrices with zero row sums have linearly independent eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let  $Y \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times N}$ be a complex symmetric (but not Hermitian) matrix such that $Y = Y^\mathrm{T}$ , and it is known that $Y\mathbb{1}_{N} = 0$, where $\mathbb{1}_{N}$ is the vector of all ones.

Is this matrix $Y$ always diagonalizable? I know in general complex symmetric matrices are not.

EDIT: Michael provided a counterexample to this. However, if it is further known that all off-diagonal elements have non-positive real-parts and the zero eigenvalue corresponding to the eigenvector $\mathbb{1}_{N}$ is simple (i.e. algebraic and geometric multiplicity 1), is Y diagonalizable in that case?

Comment: See my edited post

Comment: Thank you, Michael. That settles it.

Answer (score 1):

No. Here is counterexample:
$$
Y = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & -1\\
1 & -1 + i\sqrt3 & -i\sqrt3\\
-1 & -i\sqrt3 & 1 + i\sqrt3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Jordan normal form of $Y$ is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & i\sqrt3 & 1\\
0 & 0 & i\sqrt3
\end{pmatrix}
$$

**EDIT**

Unfortunately, no. Jordan normal form of
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & -2\\
0 & 1 + i\sqrt3 & -1 - i\sqrt3\\
-2 & -1 - i\sqrt3 & 3 + i\sqrt3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 3 + i\sqrt3 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 3 + i\sqrt3
\end{pmatrix}.
$$